# Customized backend interface in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Is it possible to customize the backend interface of Magento. The requirements include:

1. A custom theme for the backend
2. Removing all the default menu in the admin panel such as catalog, Mobile, Promotions, etc and replacing them with custom menus. For example, there will be a menu for managing all the order related tasks, another one for managing all the customer related tasks and so on.
3. The content of each page under the above mentioned menus will have custom layouts.

I am aware of the fact that, the layout changes can be managed through themes but I am not sure how to implement customized menus. Should I create a different module for rendering this customized backend interface? This is my first project on Magento. Please advise on the implementation of these requirements.

Comment: You mean the design of the admin/backend panel?

Comment: What I need is no just customizing the styling and layout but creating new menu groups in the admin panel and rendering data corresponding to the new menus.

Comment: ohh I see but I just want to remind you that you can kill any chances of upgrading your templates later on.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new adminhtml theme

Start by adding a new folder inside the **app/design/adminhtml/default** folder. To start out, the folder should also contain one sub-folders called template.

So, for example, you add a folder called mytheme, and inside it you add another folder called template.

Overriding Magento configuration

All you have to do is add a new config.xml file inside **app/code/local/MyCompany/Adminhtml/etc**. Add the following code inside the file:

Note: if you created this file by following one of my earlier guides you don’t have to create it again and you would simply add the  section at the appropriate location inside the existing file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompany_Adminhtml>
            <version>0.1.1</version>
        </MyCompany_Adminhtml>
    </modules>
    <stores>
        <admin>
            <!-- override default admin design package and theme -->
            <design>
                <package>
                    <name>default</name>
                </package>
                <theme>
                    <default>mytheme</default>
                </theme>
            </design>
        </admin>
    </stores>
</config>
```

You will also have to tell Magento about this new module in an XML file placed inside **/app/etc/modules**. This file could be called MyCompany.xml and inside you would copy/paste:

Note: if you created this file by following one of my earlier guides you don’t have to create it again.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompany_Adminhtml>
        <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Adminhtml />
            </depends>
        </MyCompany_Adminhtml>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Changing template files

Now to change the default Magento templates you basically copy the .phtml files from the **app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template** folder into your own template folder and change the contents of the .phtml file to suit your needs.

For example, if you want to change the login box and remove the Magento copyright message:

Copy **app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/login.phml** into the **app/design/adminhtml/default/mytheme/template** folder and then change the

to put your own legal note.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to customize the Magento backend.Please try this way.

But developer must be the main admin user and client be the second admin user.Because the main admin user can set privileges for other users.

***Step 1: Create a New User***

1. From the Admin menu, select System > Permissions > Users.
2. Click the Add New User button.
3. In the Account Information section, do the following:
     Enter the User Name for account.The User Name should be easy to remember. It is not case-sensitive. For example, if your user name is “John,” you can also log in as “john.”

   Complete the following information:
       First Name
       Last Name
       Email addressThis email address must be different from the one that is associated with your original Admin account.

   Assign the Password for the account.

   The password should be seven or more characters long, and include both letters and numbers.

   In the Password Confirmation box, repeat the password to make sure it was entered correctly.
4. Set This Account is to “Active.”

***Step 2: Define the Role***

1. In the User Information panel on the left, click User Role. Then, in
   the list of Roles, select Administrators. (Initially, it will be the
   only role available.)
2. When complete, click the Save User button.You now have two accounts
   with Administrator access.

Comment: This exactly doesn't solve the issue. It is possible to create users with lower privileges than the admin, so that we can hide menus depending on the user role. What I need is removing some menu items as well as adding new menu items in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

1. Customize interface - Already have the extension to modify the interface. check it http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/v-admin.html
2. Customize menu - We need to work on seperate module and i think that it will be a big work.

Comment: Consider posting some codes and relevant analysis about the solution. Link only answers are not considered as good answers...